# Copy specific columns form several sheet to master

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy

i have a Master and several tabs am using a Query to copy ( Mirror ) specific columns as below :

select Col1,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col1 is not null

and the sheets were 12 sheet populating the data to the Master

while at the same time i have a script which i used to remove any work done in the master to another sheet, the issue is anytime i remove the entire row it returns back to populate in the master due to the query

i was willing to use a script to copy the same work as the query but one time only, as if i want to delete any specific row from the master will not be copy again :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!A4:M","Sheet2!A4:M","Sheet3!A4:M");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true})}
```

which is not working correctly, your help and advice will highly appriciated.

Comment: It's unclear to me which Spreadsheet app you are using, since this is not pure javascript or jquery as marked in the question. I think I got your question you just want a one time action to copy the data from 12 sheets into 1, but not synced? But without knowing the Spreadsheet application and in which context this is running, I think nobody can answer this question.

Comment: @overflowed, appriciated your kind response actually am adding this script in google sheet while i was using originally query to pull the data : QUERY({JAN!A4:M;FEB!A4:M;MAR!A4:M;APR!A4:M;MAY!A4:M;JUN!A4:M;JUL!A4:M;AUG!A4:M;SEP!A4:M;OCT!A4:M;NOV!A4:M;DEC!A4:M},"select Col1,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col1 is not null",0)

what am looking for as you figure it out, i want one time copy and if i delete or move the data from the master will not be populated again, anticipate your kind help with this matter, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

The following script will copy the data in `A4:M` from every sheet specified in the `sheetNames` array to the `Master` sheet.

- [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) sheet specified in `sheetNames` get the values in `A4:M` and add [concatenate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) them iteratively to a current array `data`. In this way, `data` will contain the values of all selected sheets in the range `A4:M`.
- Then [set the values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object)) to the `Master` sheet, starting from cell `A1`. Feel free to change that part:

  ```
  destSheet.getRange(1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data); // cell A1 (1,1)
  ```

### Solution:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  const sheetNames = ['Sheet1','Sheet3']; //add sheets here
  let data = [];
  sheetNames.forEach(shn=>{
     let sh = ss.getSheetByName(shn);
     let mR = sh.getRange('A4:A').getValues().filter(String).length+3;
     let temp = sh.getRange('A4:M'+mR).getValues().
                map(arr =>  arr.filter((_,c) => ![1,2,3].includes(c)));
     data=data.concat(temp);
  });
  destSheet.getRange(4,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
};
```

Comment: appreciate your kind help with this matter i did add the script to google sheet while i have 2 request, i don't want col 2,3,4 to be included in the copy at the master and second can it be start copying from row 4 to row 4 and continue also it will be act automatically without pressing run each time ? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l5Hn3Ew291epbzg3I_2gHfGPWeuIh-tzKErhO1jWMzg/edit#gid=563625061 . Thank a lot

Comment: appreciate your kind follow up i did apply the script to the sample sheet i provided earlier it looks like the exception is not sync as each sheet copy different data from the other to the master, if you have a also it did not start from the 4 row and copy to the 4 row. my question is about onEdit as i add a check box in coulmn in is it possible to copy when the box is checked ? Thank you for all the help and support

Comment: @Adabsiz is there a particular reason you have so many checkboxes? You only need one right? so when you click on a particular checkbox, the data of the sheet is copied to the Master file. Correct? BTW I updated my code. You can try it out.

Comment: @Adabsiz could you please post your `onEdit` request as a separate question ?since it is a whole different code. So future readers can benefit from both questions. Consider accepting this answer if it worked for you (I already tested it and it worked for me) and post a new question with exact details about the checkboxes and send me here the url of the question so I can have a look at it.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help and advice, i did post new question as requested on the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65865931/one-time-copy-specific-columns-form-multiple-sheets-with-condition-only-when-a-c ; anticipate your usual help. thanks again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227741/discussion-between-marios-and-adabsiz).